# AVPlayer - Retrieve audio tracks in all formats

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, tvos

I'm working on a tvOS application where I'm using the `AVPlayer` to play an HLS playlist which provides audio in two formats for some languages. For example:

- French (AAC)
- French (EC-3)
- English

I'm trying to display a custom dialog that would allow the users to select between each of these tracks.

The playlist looks like this:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-mp4a.40.2",NAME="Français",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="fr",URI="..."
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-ec-3",NAME="Français",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="fr",URI="..."
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-mp4a.40.2",NAME="English",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="..."
```

The problem is that, from what I can tell, the `AVPlayer` groups the tracks by language and it never returns all the 3 tracks.

```
(lldb) po player?.currentItem?.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .audible)

▿ Optional<AVMediaSelectionGroup>
  - some : <AVAssetMediaSelectionGroup: 0x283961940, options = (
    "<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x2839a5a00, language = fr, mediaType = 'soun', title = Français, default = YES>",
    "<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x2839a5b00, language = en, mediaType = 'soun', title = English>"
), allowsEmptySelection = YES>
```

I went deeper into the French item (`player?.currentItem?.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .audible)?.options.first`) but I still couldn't find anything useful. I also tried looking at other fields from the `AVPlayer` with no success.

Even when I use the `AVPlayerViewController` I only see two audio tracks to choose from.

Is there any way to get all the available audio tracks?

Answer (score 3):

So the issue here is actually the playlist. If you check the HLS specification, there are some notes explaining this under the Rendition Groups subsection of `EXT-X-MEDIA` (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-07#section-4.4.6.1.1)

> A Playlist MAY contain multiple Groups of the same TYPE in order to
>      provide multiple encodings of that media type.  If it does so, each
>      Group of the same TYPE MUST have the same set of members, and each
>      corresponding member MUST have identical attributes with the
>      exception of the URI and CHANNELS attributes.

Generally, the way to think about it is, anything within a given `GROUP-ID` is selectable by the user (and so AVFoundation reveals it to you). But which `GROUP-ID` is playing is selected by the player, and (for this scenario) this is determined by the `AUDIO` attribute of the `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` that the player has selected.

If you want the surround audio track to be selectable, then it needs to exist in the same `GROUP-ID` as the rest of the `AUDIO` tracks. If you don't have control of the manifest, you can test this by re-writing the `GROUP-ID` of the surround French track (using something like Charles Proxy), from `audio-ec-3` to `audio-mp4a.40.2`; it should appear in AVFoundation after that. But a word of warning, for the HLS to remain valid, the `CODECS` attribute of all of the `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` tags have to be updated to include the `CODECS` defined by the surround track (otherwise playback failure may occur).

If you want to leave it up to the player to select, and you do not have a surround English track, you still have to give the English option in the surround group to remain valid HLS, but you can just leave the `URI` identical to the one defined in the stereo group. Again `CODECS` will have to be updated in this scenario.

This video from WWDC gives a good explanation of all of this (relevant section starts around 42:39): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/502/